# The square-integrability of $p$ and $\nabla u$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, integration, convolution

We consider the stationary Stokes problem in $\mathbb{R}^n$
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dvg}{\nabla\cdot}
\begin{cases} \Delta u + \nabla p = f  & \text{ in  $\mathbb{R}^n$} \\
\Dvg u =0.
\end{cases}
$$
Applying the $\operatorname{div}$ or $\Dvg$ operator to both side of the above equation, we get
$ -\Delta p =  -\Dvg f $, then the solution $( u, p )$ is written in terms of the fundamental solution $\Gamma$ of $-\Delta$ as
$$
\begin{split}
 u & = \Gamma \star  f + \Gamma \star \nabla (\Dvg  \Gamma) \star f \\
 p & = - (\Dvg \Gamma) \star f
\end{split}
$$
where
$$
\Gamma(x)= 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{d(d-2) \omega_{d}} \dfrac{1}{|x|^{d-2}} & (d \geq 3), \\ 
\\
-\dfrac{1}{2 \pi} \ln |x| & (d=2).
\end{cases}
$$
$\omega_{d}$ is the volume of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

When $n=2$, I am confused a little bit. I am trying to prove the square-integrability of $p$, and $\nabla u$ when $f \in W^{1,1}(\Bbb R^2)$, and to do this I thought about the Hardy–Littlewood–Sobolev inequality but that somehow couldn't help:
I would be so grateful if you share any thoughts.

Comment: I changed an occurrence of $\div$ `\div` to your macro $\nabla\cdot$ `\Div`.  I hope this was correct.

Comment: @LSpice yeah it's okay, I am coming from French Schools where  we're used to \div operator instead of $\nabla . $

Comment: Really, the French school writes $\div f$?

Comment: @LSpice the fault was mine: I used the reserved LaTEX word `\div` = $\div$ to identify the divergence operator I defined (hidden) in side the first LaTEX statement (`\DeclareMathOperator{\Dvg}{\nabla\cdot}`= $\operatorname{\nabla\cdot}$). Samiha says that the French school preferentially  uses $\operatorname{div}$ instead of $\operatorname{\nabla\cdot}$: in the OP this can be readily done if one puts `\operatorname{div}` instead of `\nabla\cdot` in the hidden definition of `\Dvg`.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri, the problem was not with the use of the TeX macro, but with forgetting case sensitivity.  Calling a macro `\Div` is just fine, since TeX does not already know this name; and even calling it `\div` is OK (since MathJax is relaxed about re-definitions where LaTeX would require a `\renewcommand`); but calling it `\Div` and invoking it as `\div` does not work.  It was this that I [corrected](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/414667/3); there was no need to change to `\Dvg` (although, as long as that is consistent, it does no more harm than `\Div`).